# How can I properly cumulate changes in a "detail" view controller from choosing UITableView cells without stacking infinite controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView, and a *detail* UIViewController for displaying an NSNumber in a UILabel and accepting the desired UITableView change. In an event much simpler than my original, I have a NSNumber initialized as 0, which I want to selectively add numbers to. Using a UITableView, I select a number to increase by and press an accept button when I want to confirm the change.

> Add 1, Add 5, Add 10, Add 50, Add 100, etcetera...

This actually changes the "important" variable to the correct value instead of my using a temp value shown in a UILabel in the detail view controller:

... inside tableController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"])
    {
        detailController* dc = (detailController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        dc.v2Temp = dc.v2Number;

        if([self.selectedTitle isEqualToString:@"Add 1"]) // If selected cell title matches
        {
            // Store value as temporary NSNumber
            dc.v2Temp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(self.tempNumber.intValue + 1)];
        }

       // ... more cases ...
    }
}
```

The problem I am having with my test bench iPhone application is that I seemingly push another controller onto the navigation controller stack once the "accept" Bar Button Item is pressed and the segue is performed to switch back to the UITableViewController. I want to be able to take my accepted NSNumber and constantly add new numbers to it to cumulate a sum until I press something like a finish button to stop the entire process. How can I accomplish this without stacking controllers. I wish to be able to just flip back and forth between a UITableView and a detail view controller while sharing the accepted cumulated NSNumber. I believe that I am simply unfamiliar with how to accomplish this, and have had no luck with finding other issues of the same type on the internet. Thank you.

Code:

detailController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface detailController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *v2Label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *v2Number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *v2Temp;

- (IBAction)acceptChange:(id)sender;

@end
```

detailController.m

```
#import "detailController.h"
#import "tableController.h"

@interface detailController ()

@end

@implementation detailController

- (IBAction)acceptChange:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"acceptSegue" sender:nil];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.v2Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.v2Temp.integerValue];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"acceptSegue"])
    {
        self.v2Number = self.v2Temp;
        tableController* tc = (tableController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        tc.tempNumber = self.v2Number;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: did you want to short your if else loop? And one more question is did the detailSegue is call from tableController

Comment: I gladly welcome an alternative solution to my if else conditions...  if there is a more logical and organized approach. And yes, the tableController segues (push) to the detailSegue, which segues (push) to the tableController when a change is accepted.

Comment: OK then you have to use a custom delegate for pass the value don't use perform segue to set value if you do that it will be queued. use popviewcontroller before this set Number using delegate

Comment: What exactly will be queued? And is set and pop before viewDidLoad for a new controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a global variable that keeps track of your total score. In iOS you could say

```
extern int global_variable;
```

and then just initialize it to zero in viewDidLoad in the first view controller and then add to it/ reset it if you wanted at any other time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That sounds like a great idea actually. My only concern is how this approach fairs in terms of memory and performance. Is this a typical solution to issues similar to mine? Thanks.

Comment: if you have a small amount of data that you are looking to share, this is a great way to accomplish that task. Bigger amounts of data will require a class that follows the singleton data pattern where you basically have one shared instance of this class that persists throughout the lifetime of your application

Comment: Thanks Patrick. So, perhaps sharing something like arrays or even UIImage data... I'd want to use a class approach?

Comment: I believe so, that is what I would do. Also you want to assure that this data is not getting manipulated by multiple places at the same time.